# Node eval script does not work as expected

Tags: node.js, regex, bash, shell

Environment: Node12 on Ubuntu server

Here is content of my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine

USER root

ENV GLIBC_VER=2.31-r0
```

When I run this command

```
node -e "const fileName = './Dockerfile';const pattern = new RegExp('.*');console.log('pattern is: ', pattern);const fs = require('fs');const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8');const isMatch=pattern.test(fileName);if(isMatch === false){console.log('')}else {console.log(data.match(pattern)[0])}"
```

The output is:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
```

But when I change the pattern from `.*` to `FROM.*`, it does not work

When I run this command

```
node -e "const fileName = './Dockerfile';const pattern = new RegExp('FROM.*','i');console.log('pattern is: ', pattern);const fs = require('fs');const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8');const isMatch=pattern.test(fileName);if(isMatch === false){console.log('')}else {console.log(data.match(pattern)[0])}"
```

it does not print anything?!

I also try to change `new RegExp('FROM.*','i')` to `/FROM.*/` but it does not work at all.

What is wrong with it?

[image]

Comment: The pattern is being tested against `fileName` rather than `data`

Answer (score 1):

The regexp pattern is being tested against the `fileName` in the original, rather than the `data`.

```
node -e '
  const fs = require("fs");
  const fileName = "./Dockerfile";
  const pattern = new RegExp("FROM.*","i");
  const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, "utf-8");
  const match = pattern.exec(data);
  if (match) {
    console.log(match[0])
  } else {
    process.exit(1)
  }
'
```

A couple of notes:

Shell escaping is harder than node double quote escaping, so use single quotes for the shell command (or even better, package this in a script).

Use `Regexp.prototype.exec` rather than using `.match` on a variable as the RegExp is a known value and less error prone.

New lines make the world go round, even in oneliners.

Comment: lol this is my mistake, thank you alot for your help, nice tips also!!

Comment: the reason I use double quote to wrap the code because it is very convenient when you use it with bash script, I have an alias like that `matchTextInFile(){
  node -e "const fileName = '$1';const pattern = new RegExp('$2');console.log('pattern is: ', pattern);const fs = require('fs');const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8');const isMatch=pattern.test(data);if(!isMatch){console.log('')}else {console.log(data.match(pattern)[0])}"
}` here you can pass parameter from outside and it works like grep (with regex)!

Comment: Understood, it's just very easy to get into trouble. Any arguments with a single quote will trip up that code. `argv` is a safer way to inject values: `node -pe 'process.argv[1]' hello`

Comment: Thanks! `node -pe 'process.argv[1]' hello` should be quite useful!